# Build multi-dimensional then add to Table

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, foreach, sql-insert

how can I create a single multidimensional array from 2 or more foreach loops:

```
$arr = array();

//loop 1
foreach (dogs[1] as $key => $url)
{
$arr[$key]['pos'] = $key;
$arr[$key]['place'] = "2";
$arr[$key]['title'] = "3";
$arr[$key]['picurl'] = trim($dogs[2][$key]);
$arr[$key]['picwidth'] = "5";
$arr[$key]['picheight'] = "6";
$arr[$key]['titleurl'] = $url;
}


//loop 2
foreach (cats[1] as $key => $url)
{
$arr[$key]['pos'] = $key;
$arr[$key]['place'] = "2";
$arr[$key]['title'] = "3";
$arr[$key]['picurl'] = trim($cats[2][$key]);
$arr[$key]['picwidth'] = "5";
$arr[$key]['picheight'] = "6";
$arr[$key]['titleurl'] = $url;
}
```

then add the entire new multidimensional array to a mysql table where each column in the table called 'links'  already corresponds to the row names in the array (pos, place, title, picurl, picwidth, picheight, titleurl) ... (which have been pre-populated by the two foreach loops prior to database insertion)

Unsure of how to connect to database as yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to connect to the database using either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). I prefer PDO personally, but either one works. Then you'll want to [prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) a statement, and then [execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) it within a `foreach` loop on the array. Be sure you prepare it with parameters which you then bind in the execute statement; do not insert the variables directly into the query string.

Comment: would you know how to combine the two foreach loops to build the 1 array and forget about the insertion for the moment please?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but maybe you want to append the dogs and cats arrays and `foreach` over that appended array?

Comment: yes, dogs + cats = arr (I just thought it'd be best to build up arr by cycling through dogs and then cats)

Comment: Oh. You're best off just using the language's append, it'll be well-optimized.